# c++ - error C3646: unknown override specifier

Tags: c++, syntax

I modified my project and after compiling there pop up some weird error.

```
#ifndef BART_RAY_TRACER_MESH_H
#define BART_RAY_TRACER_MESH_H

#include <vector>
#include "assert.h"
#include "vec3f.h"

class Triangle;

class Mesh {
public:
    uint32_t nverts;
    bool _is_static;
    vec3f *verts;
    vec3f *_verts_world;
    Material material; 
    // 2 error occurs at the line below
    Matrix4x4 _trans_local_to_world; // '_trans_local_to_world': unknown override specifier & missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    Matrix4x4 _trans_local_to_world_inv;
    TransformHierarchy *_trans_hierarchy;   

    std::vector<Triangle* > triangles;
    // ...
};
#endif
```

When I change the order of the declaration a little bit, the error always occurs the line after `Material material`, but with different message:

```
#ifndef BART_RAY_TRACER_MESH_H
#define BART_RAY_TRACER_MESH_H

#include <vector>
#include "assert.h"
#include "vec3f.h"

class Triangle;

class Mesh {
public:
    uint32_t nverts;
    bool _is_static;
    vec3f *verts;
    vec3f *_verts_world;
    Material material; 
    // 2 error occurs at the line below
    TransformHierarchy *_trans_hierarchy; // error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*' & error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    Matrix4x4 _trans_local_to_world;
    Matrix4x4 _trans_local_to_world_inv;  

    std::vector<Triangle* > triangles;
    // ...
};
#endif
```

I've searched for similar questions on SO but none seems useful.
I've checked my `vec3f`, `Triangle` class definition in case there are missing semicolons but I can't find any.

Can any one help?

Comment: Where is Material defined?

Comment: What dio you get if you put something primitive like `double wtf;` after `material`?

Comment: @starmole Hi! I have a `shape.h` where `Triangle` is defined. And `material.h` is included in `shape.h`. I don't know if `class Material` would be included when I use `class Triangle` as a forward declaration. But i tried to include `material.h` here, still the same problem.

Comment: Based on the errors, it sounds like neither `Matrix4x4` nor `TransformHierarchy` are declared yet. You may be missing includes for both.

Comment: You can forward declare a pointer (like Triangle) but a member like Material of TransformHierarchy needs to be fully defined.

Answer (score 18):

This is just another Microsoft cock-up. Here it is in essence:

```
class C
  {
  x y ;
  } ;
```

If you submit this to a sensible compiler like g++, it gives you a helpful error message:

> 3:2: error: 'x' does not name a type

MSVC, on the other hand, comes up with this gibberish:

> (3): error C3646: 'y': unknown override specifier
>   (3): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int

With this key, you can decrypt Microsoft's error message into:

> error: 'Matrix4x4' does not name a type

Answer (score 1):

The error is most likely because that `TransformHierarchy` and `Matrix4x4` are not defined.

If they are not defined in `"assert.h"` and `"vec3f.h"`, this should be the case.

Forward declaration is enough only when you use the reference types and/or pointer types only. Therefore, to forward declare `Triangle` is OK. But forward declare `Triangle` does not mean your `shape.h` is processed. Neither does your `material.h` which is included in `shape.h`.

Therefore, all names in `material.h` is not visible from this code. 
`TransformHierarchy` and `Matrix4x4` are not recognized by the compiler. 
Many of the compliers will complain with words similar to `"missing type specifier - int assumed"`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was found that a header file had the following directives for a class [ie, myComboBoxData]

```
#ifndef __COMBOBOXDATA__
#define __COMBOBOXDATA__
// ... 
class myComboBoxData
{
    // ...
}
#endif
```

As another class below tried to use `myComboBoxData` class

```
class TypeDlg : public CDialog
{
    myComboBoxData cbRow,cbCol;
    // ...
}
```

the error message popped up as above:

> "error C3646: 'cbRow': unknown override specifier".

**Solution:**

The problem was the directive name (`__COMBOBOXDATA__`) was already used by OTHER header.

Thus, make sure to use some other name like (`__myCOMBOBOXDATA__`).