# C++ unknown override specifier

Tags: c++

as the title said I have a problem with a object's method. It has to return a class type but I get an error when I try to compile.

Here my code:

main.h

```
#pragma once

#ifndef _Main_H
#define _Main_H

#include <iostream>



#include "Vector3.h"
#include "Object.h"


#endif
```

Vector3.h

```
#pragma once

#ifndef _Vector3_H
#define _Vector3_H

#include "main.h"


class Vector3
{
public:
    float x, y, z;

    Vector3(float x, float y, float z = 0);

    ~Vector3();

};

#endif
```

Vector3.cpp

```
#include "Vector3.h"


Vector3::Vector3(float x, float y, float z)
{
    this->x = x; this->y = y; this->z = z;
}

Vector3::~Vector3() = default;
```

Object.h

```
#pragma once

#ifndef _Object_H
#define _Object_H

#include "main.h"


class Object
{
private:
    float x, y, z;

public:
    Object(float x, float y, float z);

    ~Object();

    Vector3 getCoordinates();


};

#endif
```

Object.cpp

```
#include "Object.h"

Object::Object(float x, float y, float z) {
    this->x = x; this->y = y; this->z = z;
}

Object::~Object() = default;


Vector3 Object::getCoordinates() {
    return Vector3(this->x, this->y, this->z);
}
```

So I get the errors on Object.h (on this line: ***Vector3 getCoordinates();***):

'getCoordinates': unknown override specifier

syntax error: '('

unespected token(s) preceding ';'

How can i solve this?

Edit:
Compiling with Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c++ - error C3646: unknown override specifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46188302/c-error-c3646-unknown-override-specifier)

Comment: Clean compile from clang, gcc, MSVC - live - https://godbolt.org/z/GGYjbav1h

Comment: Unrelated: Why are `Vector3.h` and `Object.h` including `main.h`? That just seems wrong.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_Main_H`, `_Vector3_H`, `_Object_H`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don’t use them in your code.

Comment: @RichardCritten Edit: I'm using Visual studio 2019, so it's a Visual studio issue?

Comment: @PeteBecker: Thanks I didn't know that!

Comment: @TedLyngmo oh, I this was the problem. Now seems to compile. Thank you!

Comment: #include "main.h"
class Vector3   why bother including main.h ?
why use both pragma once and ifndef ?

Comment: @WilliamDG  MSVC 19.12 is MSVS 2019 from a few months ago (you can change the version to whatever you have).  As it compiles with all the code in one file this proves to me it's an include order or include guard problem, with a non-helpful error message as EtiennedeMartel linked above.