# C++ Error C3646: unknown override specifier

Tags: c++

I am getting a weird error message when compiling with msvc (VS2022 Community). The Error is: `Main.h(20,11): error C3646: 'Setup': unknown override specifier`
(Followed by a bunch of seemingly random Syntax Errors)

I did some research, the most useful answer was it being a circular include, but I don't think that is the case here.

My Code is separated into 3 Files:

Main.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <WinSock2.h>

namespace socketLib {

    enum SOCKET_SETUP_ERROR
    {
        ERR_OK = 0,
        ERR_INIT,
        ERR_SOCK,
        ERR_BIND,
        ERR_LISTEN
    };

    class TCPSocket
    {
    public:
        ~TCPSocket() { Cleanup(); }
        uint8_t Setup(uint16_t port);
        void Cleanup();

        bool Poll();
    private:
        WSAData m_wsaData;
        SOCKET m_serverSocket;
        sockaddr_in m_serverAddr;
    };

}
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Main.h"

namespace socketLib {

    uint8_t TCPSocket::Setup(uint16_t port)
    {
        if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &m_wsaData) != 0) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to initialize WinSock.\n";
            return ERR_INIT;
        }

        m_serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (m_serverSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to create socket.\n";
            WSACleanup();
            return ERR_SOCK;
        }

        m_serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        m_serverAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
        m_serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

        if (bind(m_serverSocket, (sockaddr*)&m_serverAddr, sizeof(m_serverAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to bind socket.\n";
            Cleanup();
            return ERR_BIND;
        }

        if (listen(m_serverSocket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            std::cerr << "Listen failed.\n";
            Cleanup();
            return ERR_LISTEN;
        }

        std::cout << "Server running on port " << port << "\n";
        return ERR_OK;
    }

    void TCPSocket::Cleanup()
    {
        closesocket(m_serverSocket);
        WSACleanup();
    }

    bool TCPSocket::Poll()
    {
        SOCKET clientSocket = accept(m_serverSocket, nullptr, nullptr);
        if (clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            std::cerr << "Accept failed.\n";
            return false;
        }

        char buffer[1024];
        int bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        if (bytesReceived > 0) {
            send(clientSocket, buffer, bytesReceived, 0);
        }

        closesocket(clientSocket);
    }

}
```

and App.cpp (which contains the main function):

```
#include "socketLib/Main.h"

int main()
{
    socketLib::TCPSocket socket;

    socket.Setup(8080);
    
    while (true)
    {
        socket.Poll();
    }
}
```

The include Path seems to be fine.
I'd be glad if someone could help, thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like it couldn’t find `uint8_t`, whether due to a missing `#include` or a missing `std::`.

Comment: `#include <cstdint>` - Also note that `Poll` doesn't return a `bool` in all cases so the problem will have undefined behavior.

Comment: "problem" = "program" above :-)

Comment: Thank You, including cstdint fixed it. I just don't know why it was giving such an unrelated seeming error massage...

Comment: Do you need the contents of your source files to reproduce the error? What if you eliminated `App.cpp` and reduced `Main.cpp` to `#include "Main.h"`? Same first error? What if you removed everything from the definition of `TCPSocket` except `Setup`? The less code used to reproduce the error, the fewer red herrings.

Comment: [My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58571593/428857) explains everything. Ye Gods, haven't they fixed it by now?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to include `<cstdint>` into `Main.h` to get the `uint8_t` and `uint16_t` types. Thanks, @Davis Herring

Comment: They should still be qualified with `std::`. There is no guarantee that they are also defined in the global namespace.